# How to import content from a text file and add them to variables

Tags: python

I have a settings file for a monopoly like game I'm making, the settings file has parameters like the number of people playing and whatnot, I would like to know how to import the settings from that text file and bring it into different variables, for example, having number of players in the settings file go to a numPlayers variable in the actual code so I can use it for other games and also usee the settings in the code

This is my code:

```
    def inputs(line, typeinp=None, start=None, end=None):
        while True:
            string = input(line)
            if typeinp != None:
                try:
                    if typeinp == "string":
                        string = str(string)
                    elif typeinp == "integer":
                        string = int(string)
                    if start != None and end != None:
                        while not (string >= start and string <= end):
                            print("Please input a number between", str(start) + "-" + str(end))
                            string = int(input(line))
                    break
                except:
                    print("Plese input a", typeinp)
            else:
                break
        return string


    # Settings file, if user chooses to run setup this is all the setup questions


    def gameSettingsSetup():
        settingsCheck = open("settings.txt", "r")
        print("Lets setup")
        # Int Setup questions
        numPlayers = str(inputs('How many real players are playing: ', "integer"))
        numAIplayers = str(inputs('How many AI players will be playing?: ', "integer"))
        AILevel = str(inputs("What AI difficulty level would you like? (Easy, Normal, Hard): "))
        while True:
            if AILevel == "Easy" or AILevel == "Normal" or AILevel == "Hard":
                startingMoney = str(inputs("How much money does everyone start with? Max: 10 000 (Keep in mind "
                                           "this does not affect the property prices) ", "integer", 100, 10000))
                break

            else:
                print("Please enter a valid input (make sure to capitalize the first letter)")
                AILevel = str(inputs("What AI difficulty level would you like? (Easy, Normal, Hard): "))

        # sends over the settings into the text file as well as monoset check
        if "MonoSet1-1" in settingsCheck.read():
            with open("settings.txt", "w") as file:
                file.write("MonoSet1-1: true" + "\n")
                file.write("numPlayer: " + numPlayers + "\n")
                file.write("numAIplayer: " + numAIplayers + "\n")
                file.write("AI Level: " + AILevel + "\n")
                file.write("startingMoney: " + startingMoney + "\n")
                file.close()

        # Allows for access to the settings file and drops values into a list
        settings = []
        with open("settings.txt") as file:
            for line in file:
                line = line.split(":")
                line = line[1]
                line = line.rstrip("\n")
                line = line[1:]
                line = line.split(" ")
                try:
                    for x in range(len(line)):
                        line[x] = int(line[x])
                    line = (line[0], line[1])
                except:
                    line = line[0]
                    settings.append(line)
        file.close()
        print("Alright the setup is complete, Your game will start now....")
        time.sleep(1)

        return settingsCheck, settings
```

Comment: Consider using a settings.json file instead of a text file. That would allow you to access variables as keys in a dict.

Comment: better use other format to keep data - file JSON, .ini, yaml, or module [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html)

Comment: If you like the `.ini` to store settings file format consider using [configparser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html)

Comment: If you want to be able to edit the file then I'd recommend .ini/configparser.  It's too easy to accidentally corrupt json and yaml files when editing.